# If hands are in water through the night must they be washed in the morning?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

If one sleeps through the night with hands in water must one wash hands for netilat yadayim in the morning?

Comment: Why do you think that would help regarding the right-left-alternating business?

Comment: It seems you are trying to come up with a situation where the ruach raah will not happen. 

However, let's look at a case where one needed to wash after waking up and instead of pouring over them,  placed his hands in water.

The Shulchan Aruch in siman 4 siff 12 says shaking ones hands in water will help for krias shema and tefila but won't take of ruach raah (that needs pouring specifically). Shaking them in three different waters or in a river is questionable if it helps for ruach raah.

Comment: But i do like the question. It's cute. +1

Comment: @DoubleAA Who said anything about ruach raah? Maybe rikitikitembo is going with the opinions that it is for cleanliness or _b'riah chadasha_.

Comment: @user6591 ^^^^^^^

Comment: @mevaqesh I didn't deny such a possibility.

Comment: According to the Rosh/Gra opinion that netilah is for teffila. You would still have to wash. כן נראה לי

Comment: @mevaqesh i think i covered that. Did you actually read what i wrote?

Comment: @mefaresh if you check the s.a. i mentioned tefila is more lenient in this regard.

Comment: @user6591 yes although you reference the distinction between prayer and the evil spirit, you still write that it seems you are trying to come up with a situation where the evil spirit will not happen.and my question stands.maybe the op had is mind that one will be clean a la Rosh or ready for me day a la rabba.who says the op is dealing with the evil demons?

Comment: @mevaqesh true. I used the common lingo. That opening line was simply meant to convey that i understood his point was trying to cut off the reason for washing before it happened.